# Lock Android phone application to Portrait mode

Tags: android, portrait, android-screen

Can someone tell me how to lock my application to a portrait mode? Is it a simple configuration in the manifest file?

Comment: Please only do this if you have a big reason for it. It's an antipattern in Android. Users should be able to choose how to use their devices.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

Yes. Add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to the manifest under your main activity.

```
<activity android:name=".yourActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"... />
```

Answer (score 75):

Yes! It's an attribute of the activity tag:

```
<activity android:name=".yourActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" ... />
```

Comment: Do i need to add this to all the activities to lock it ?

Comment: @HarshaMV Looks to me like adding this to the main activity applies it to the entire app.

Answer (score 12):

Also, you may have to add the following to your activity element:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
```

That way, the OS won't change the orientation when the user opens a sliding keyboard.

Answer (score 6):

None of these answers worked on my system but I did find the following worked perfectly for a simple app that I developed:

Within *MainActivity.java* add:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

to *onCreate ()*

This is mine:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

I know that it is not (always) best practice locking orientation, but in special circumstances it is valid and I only want this temporarily while I continue developing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is good that you share a solution for your specific case, but you can edit your answer to format properly the code you posted, so it will be more human-readable. To do so, the code and the previous paragraph must be split by at least two linebreaks, and every line in the code block must be indented with at least 4 spaces. **Please try this out** by editing your answer, and you will see by yourself how it makes your answer look much better.

Comment: You will find complete useful tips to improve answers in general in the section [How do I post a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).
But, in your case, you will find [this section about markdown in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) much more interesting, I think. Any little improvement in your answer can make a big difference.

Comment: Thanks for the tips SebasSBM, it looked readable on my screen when I sent it but something was lost on the journey :)