# How to disable splash screen auto rotate in android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, splash-screen, autorotate

I need to disable splash screen auto rotate.

Need to show splash screen in portrait mode only. But app must rotate with auto rotate. How to do it in android studio ?

Comment: There are lot of Answer available on internet.You have to search before posting any question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lock Android phone application to Portrait mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044544/lock-android-phone-application-to-portrait-mode)

Answer (score 6):

Add in Manifest file-->

```
    <application
    .........
    >

    <activity
                android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
                  ......
                 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                 />

</application>
```

or for horizontal mode

```
<activity
        ...
        ...
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

Answer (score 5):

**In Your AndroidMainfest.xml put the screen orientation to your splash**

```
     <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 5):

In the manifest, set this for your splash screen activity:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

In manifest you can set the specific activity to be in portrait mode using

```
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add below line in your manifest file, in splash activity tag

```
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Something like below

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```

Answer (score 4):

Add to your splash activity declaration in the manifest this lines:

```
<activity
    android:name="SplashActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```

Find relevant discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-do-i-disable-orientation-change-on-android).

Answer (score 3):

You Can do it by couple of ways

**One**

Inside the `onCreate` method of your activity

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

**Two**

In `manifest file`

```
   <activity
        android:name=".NameOfYourSplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Add following code to your splash screen activity declaration in Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivityName"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges = "orientation"
              android:screenOrientation = "portrait">
```

or else add

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

to `YourActivity.onCreate()`

you can find a sample demo file [here in github](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Rotation/RotationFour/)

Answer (score 0):

try this in manifiest

```
  <activity
    android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```