# Landscape include layout in Portrait orientation

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-orientation

I'm currently developing an app that will show a physical representation of an ID card, i have this view as an XML file on both landscape and portrait mode.
My question is: is it possible to have the phone in Portrait mode and use only this layout as an include in landscape mode? The goal is to have a nice elegant ID Card shown on the screen like the picture here. Thank you.[image: As seen in the picture here]

Edit: so in other words I need to use a LANDSCAPE resource while being on PORTRAIT mode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lock Android phone application to Portrait mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044544/lock-android-phone-application-to-portrait-mode)

Comment: No, sorry it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to your Activity in the manifest and this will lock the Activity in portrait mode.